# Program or Website similar to Wiris?

Tags: specific-software

In Spain, there's a famous website called [Wiris](http://herramientas.educa.madrid.org/wiris/) that is a multi-platform website with the ability to create and calculate some of the most basic mathematical operations, but also you can save your project and continue after a while!

I was wondering if there is any other website or program similar to this, to create your own project with formulas and variables and, after only inputting the necessary data, the program calculates everything you want!

I was trying by creating autofilling sheets in Microsoft Word or LaTeX but they don't convince me (also in LaTeX I couldn't)

So, any suggestions?

Comment: excel I suppose.

Comment: It's unfortunate that Wiris is a java applet. Java applets are becoming an increasingly untenable software platform.

Comment: @BenCrowell Exactly! That's why I was looking for other opcions :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having taken a quick look, what you are looking for seems to be a **computer algebra system** with a workbook, into which you can save your progress. The most well-known is of course [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/), but depending on what you want to do some people prefer [MatLab](http://www.mathworks.ch/products/matlab/) or [Maple](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/). For a pretty big list you can consult the [Wikipedia listing of CAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems). Here I note a few free (as in beer, and sometimes as in speech) programs or websites.

- [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) is designed as a free software replacement for MatLab, and covers many similar functionality, and uses similar syntax.
- [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is a bundle of free mathematics softwares with a more-or-less unified interface. They have currently an online service that is in beta called [SageMathCloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com/) which seems to be very similar to Wiris in terms of functionality.
- One can also make use of [SymPy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html) together with an [IPython Notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) to reproduce somewhat the Wiris experience.
- (A little bit of a shameless plug: I [wrote some code](http://williewong.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/ipython-notebook-take-2/) sometime ago for helping with algebraic computations using IPython Notebook. There is *no* built-in CAS capabilities in my code; that is to say all math must be done in your brain. It is just a convenient replacement for paper and pen when I want to be more organized about writing things down.)
- [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/) can be used with various frontends (I personally prefer [wxMaxima](http://andrejv.github.io/wxmaxima/)) to get the similar experience of having a workbook which you can save.

Comment: A wonderful answer! Thank you a lot! I'll try out some of them to see what I can get :)

Comment: plus one for sage https://sagecell.sagemath.org
plays nicely with python, latex, plots, etc

Answer (score 6):

this is Ramon from WIRIS team.

We are working on a Javascript version of WIRIS CAS. Still in beta.
[www.wiris.com/calc/](http://www.wiris.com/calc/)

Comment: The new URL for the JavaScript version of WIRIS cas is [calcme.com](https://calcme.com)